How do i actually get memory_retry_multiplier to work in cromwell on GCP?
Cromwell RetryWithMoreMemory instructions say I should set system.memory-retry-error-keys and memory_retry_multiplier in order to get retries to allocate more memory for a task when it fails with one of the strings in system.memory-retry-error-keys appearing in stderr.
I have a task failing with a memory error.  It has the string "Killed" in it, which is one of the system.memory-retry-error-keys.  The rc is 1.  But every retry has the same available memory as the first run (I know this because I run free -h right before the failure, and it gives the same message every time)
Is there example code showing successful use of this claimed feature?
